# python - append only select columns as rows

Tags: python, pandas, append, nan, newrow

Original file has multiple columns but there are lots of blanks and I want to rearrange so that there is one nice column with info. Starting with 910 rows, 51 cols (newFile df) -> Want 910+x rows, 3 cols (final df) final df has 910 rows.

[newFile sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUHiU.png)

```
for i in range (0,len(newFile)):
    for j in range (0,48):
        if (pd.notnull(newFile.iloc[i,3+j])):
            final=final.append(newFile.iloc[[i],[0,1,3+j]], ignore_index=True)
```

I have this piece of code to go through newFile and if 3+j column is not null, to copy columns 0,1,3+j to a new row. I tried append() but it adds not only rows but a bunch of columns with NaNs again (like the original file).

Any suggestions?!

Comment: Can you include an example of newFile to make it easier to understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a DataFrame and keeping column names, so adding a new columns with a value will fill the new column with NaN for the rest of the dataframe.
Plus your code is really inefficient given the double for loop. 
Here is my solution using `melt()`

```py
#creating example df
df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 51)), columns=list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'))
#reconstructing df as long version, keeping columns from index 0 to index 3
df = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[0:2])
#dropping the values that are null
df.dropna(subset=['value'],inplace=True)
#here if you want to keep the information about which column the value is coming from you stop here, otherwise you do 
df.drop(inplace=True,['variable'],axis=1)
print(df)
```